# Is there ADA-compliance certification for mathematics text books?

Tags: calculus, textbooks, usa, disability

What factors are there to consider when adopting a text as far as ADA (Americans with Disabilities Act) is concerned? Is there a certification? What do you look for in the digital version of the text? Do you have experience in this regard as far calculus books are concerned?

Comment: If you have handicapped students in your class, just contact the Student Accessibility Services office to see what accommodations are needed (normally they should contact you themselves in such cases). It is usually not about textbook/whatever ADA compliance (which is neither necessary, nor sufficient to cover all situations) but about making individual arrangements on a case by case basis in a timely manner.

Comment: This is problematic for mathematics texts. Latex/pdf and math formulas are still not well handled by most systems. However there is currently a lot of effort to improve that situation.